# Subfloats don't have the same size

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have a 3x1 subfloats as shown below and the problem is that there is a slight difference in there size dimensions, and I'm asking how this can be fixed so that they have the same size? If anyone could please advise.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.23]{1.png}}\label{1}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.23]{2.png}}\label{1}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.23]{3.png}}\label{3}
\caption{Caption}
\label{label1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Why don't you use "\includegraphics[height=2cm]{1.png}" and so on, using the same height for the other two images?

Comment: The size depends in part from the real size of each picture, your example assumes that the size is the same for the three pictures but is it real?

Comment: I do not understand. There is nothing to do with any specific subgraph-related package. Both your question and answer indicate that one need only to use `\includegraphics` properly. So why bother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed using `[width=x\linewidth]` where `x` is any number between `0` and `1`.

Comment: Well the value from `x` should be between [0-1] for the case you don't need the whole `\linewidth` magnitude but only a part of.